# String into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like:

```
     {
        "OperationResult": [
                 {
                   "CA::Read:PackageItems": {
                           "Read.PackageItem.RemoteBalanceAssigned": false,
                           "Read.PackageItem.CLSpvInfo": "1|-1#-9223372036854775000",
                           "PackageList": 
                             [ 
                               "TopSim-4GSim1GBData", 
                               "TopSim-ATBReactivation"
                             ],
                           "PackageTypeList": 
                             [
                                "optional-unsubscribed", "optional-unsubscribed"
                             ],
                          "PackageFunctionalNameList": 
                                [
                                  "FreeUnits", 
                                  "AccumulationReward+MultipleThresholds"
                                ],
                          "PackageSubStateList": 
                            [
                              "",
                              ""
                            ],
                          "PackageEligibilityList": 
                          [ 
                            true, 
                            true
                          ]
            }
        }]
    }
```

I am trying to get it into array. but I want filter this string and only put `PackageList":["xxxx-yyy","zzz-zzz"]`  and "`PackageSubStateList":[TRUE,FALSE]}`

Any thing in between should be filter out.

The resulted array should be like:

```
PackageList {
               name: xxxx-yyy,
               state: TRUE,
             }
               ....
```

Comment: Why not just parse it and access the object props?

Comment: that erm `string` looks like an object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Is that an exact copy of the string? The `"optional-"optional-unsubscribed""` looks wrong and makes it pretty much un-parsable.

Comment: my web service returns response in raw test format. I couldn't parse it using simple xml

Comment: If you have tried using simple xml to parse it, that should have been included in the question along with the code you tried.

Comment: @Fshamri In this case, you should rethink about using this service or call their support and ask for help. If response is not in the form of XML, JSON etc, then parsing will be difficult and won't make sense.

Comment: If this is your string, I saw some problem : 1/ `"optional-"optional-unsubscribed""` looks wrong for me, 2/ For me it missed `}]}` at the end to close the `{"OperationResult":[{` at the beginning

Answer (score -1):

```
//The json posted in the question is invalid, assuming valid json gets used here afterwards:
$string = '{"OperationResult":[{"CA::Read:PackageItems":{"PackageList":["xxxx-yyy","zzz-zzz"],
"PackageTypeList":["optional-unsubscribed","optional-"optional-unsubscribed""],
"PackageFunctionalNameList":["FreeUnits","AccumulationReward+MultipleThresholds"],
"PackageSubStateList":[TRUE,FALSE]}';

$object = json_decode($string);
$wanted = $object['OperationResult']['CA::Read:PackageItems'];
```

`$wanted` should now contain what you need

Comment: Could be a copy-paste error, but what the OP has posted, is not valid json.

Comment: Yeah seems like he is missing some closures at the end, I assumed valid json for this one

Comment: seems I missed when pasted the string

Comment: I have used your code. it converts the string to json object but iam getting "Undefined index: CA::Read:PackageItem" error